# Zeromq REQ-REP pattern sync on nodejs

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I have 1 application ( written in nodejs, now **A** ) which should connect via ZMQ, to another application ( written in java with akka framework, now **B** ).

**B** application is replicated on multiple servers, and application **A** should make selection by querying every **B** instance ( it should ask load application average ).

I would implement this mechanism through **`REQ`/`REP`** pattern, but I slam on this :

ZMQ in nodejs **A** offers a `REQ`/`REP` pattern with event handling, without the blocking strategies defined in ZMQ architecture.

I have investigated other approaches ( switching to axon, introducing a socket on **B** application and making socket connection ), but I would try to implement this with zeromq.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you're looking for with REQ/REP, because that pattern strictly *only* handles a request/reply/request/reply messaging pattern, and what you want is more like request**B**1/request**B**2/reply**B**1/request**B**3/reply**B**2/reply**B**3 (point being, requests and replies will be asynchronous rather than in strict series).

Without digging too deeply, this looks like it might be a good fit for a DEALER/REP socket pattern.  Your DEALER socket (in **A**) will request information from *each* of your **B** servers in a round-robin fashion, and it will be able to handle the replies from those servers as they come in, in any order (you'll just have to make it part of your message to indicate which server the reply was received from).